# PostgreSQL: Generate columns for each row in another table with value based on function result

Tags: postgresql, function, for-loop, create-table

I need some help.
I have table  № 1:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 17 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 |
| .... | ... | ... |

I have table № 2:

| id_another | val1 | val2 | val3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 17 | 100 |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | 200 |

I want to get:

| id | val1 | val2 | belongs_to_id_another_0 | belongs_to_id_another_1 | is_outlier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 | 17 | 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 1 | 5 | 6 | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| .... | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

Explanation: For each entity in Table 1 I should apply function-comparison with every entity in Table 2 (Size order for Table 1 and Table 2 is ~1000:1, so the time complexity would not be problem). The function is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_loc_inside_cls (
    loc_longitude FLOAT,
    loc_latitude FLOAT,
    cls_longitude FLOAT,
    cls_latitude FLOAT,
    cls_radius FLOAT
)
RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (2 * 6378137.0 * ASIN(SQRT(SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) + (COS(loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 ) * COS(cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0)) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2)))) * (2 * 6378137.0 * ASIN(SQRT(SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) + (COS(loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 ) * COS(cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0)) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2)))) <= cls_radius * cls_radius THEN 
    RETURN 1;
  ELSE
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

I then create as many columns as entities in Table 2 and I place there the return. is_outlier value == 1 if in these new columns the NULL value is everywhere, == NULL otherwise. Question is how I can apply this logic? Couldn't find any valid examples.

I can't think of the part where I should implement FOR LOOP logic, I managed to implement only function

Comment: The description of the desired behavior is unclear. It appears that the goal is to pivot the rows resulting from applying an undefined comparison function to each row of table 2. The arguments to the comparison function are mentioned, but not the operations that the function performs. SQL is a declarative language and as such lacks FOR LOOP constructs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before addressing the question, the following are a few points regarding general code improvement:

1. Use meaningful column names. *Latitude*, *longitude*, and *radius* convey more than *val1*, *val2*, *val3*.
2. Use the most natural data type for values. Since *is_loc_inside_cls* evaluates a logical condition, it should return a boolean.
3. Avoid using NULL as a value. NULL should generally indicate lack of value or an unknown value. In the case of *is_loc_inside_cls*, the result is known so long as none of the arguments are NULL.
4. Consider refactoring *is_loc_inside_cls* to move the numeric calculation to a function that is called by *is_loc_inside_cls*. Doing so allows the calculation to be used by other code.

The following refactors *is_loc_inside_cls* to return a boolean. The `IF` statement has been removed from the original version of the function and the result is directly returned. This version of the function returns NULL to indicate that the condition is unknown if any of the arguments are NULL; otherwise, it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_loc_inside_cls (loc_longitude float, loc_latitude float, cls_longitude float, cls_latitude float, cls_radius float)
  RETURNS boolean
  AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (2 * 6378137.0 * ASIN(SQRT(SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_latitude * PI()
    / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) + (COS(loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0) * COS(cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0)) *
    SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude *
    PI() / 180.0) / 2)))) * (2 * 6378137.0 * ASIN(SQRT(SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) *
    SIN((loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_latitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) + (COS(loc_latitude * PI() / 180.0) * COS(cls_latitude *
    PI() / 180.0)) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 - cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2) * SIN((loc_longitude * PI() / 180.0 -
    cls_longitude * PI() / 180.0) / 2)))) <= cls_radius * cls_radius;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

For the following query, I've changed the column names from *val1*, *val2*, and *val3* to *latitude*, *longitude*, and *radius*, respectively. This query uses the refactored version of *is_loc_inside_cls*, so *belongs_to_id_another_0* and *belongs_to_id_another_1* might each be TRUE, FALSE, or NULL. If either *belongs_to_id_another_0* or *belongs_to_id_another_1* is TRUE, then *is_outlier* will be FALSE regardless of the other's value. If both are FALSE, then *is_outlier* will be TRUE. If neither are TRUE and either or both are NULL, then *is_outlier* will also be NULL, indicating that the state could not be determined.

```
SELECT
  table_1.id,
  table_1.latitude,
  table_1.longitude,
  bool_and(
    CASE table_2.id
    WHEN 0 THEN
      t.is_inside_cls
    END) AS belongs_to_id_another_0,
  bool_and(
    CASE table_2.id
    WHEN 1 THEN
      t.is_inside_cls
    END) AS belongs_to_id_another_1,
  bool_and(NOT t.is_inside_cls)
    OR nullif (bool_or(t.is_inside_cls IS NULL), TRUE) AS is_outlier
  FROM
    table_1
  CROSS JOIN table_2
  JOIN LATERAL (
    VALUES (is_loc_inside_cls (table_1.latitude, table_1.longitude, table_2.latitude, table_2.longitude, table_2.radius))) t (is_inside_cls) ON TRUE
GROUP BY
  table_1.id,
  table_1.latitude,
  table_1.longitude
ORDER BY
  table_1.id;
```

This query can easily be extended to support additional rows by copying the pattern for the *belongs_to_id_another_** columns. The logic for *is_outlier* is not dependent on the number of rows in *table_2*.

If it is available in the target environment, consider using the *crosstab* function that is provided by the *tablefunc* PostgreSQL extension. If the *tablefunc* extension is not available and there is a need to support an arbitrary number of rows from table_2, then create a function to dynamically generate the SQL and then execute the resulting query.

Comment: Thank you very much for help! This works as expected.